# CruiseControl.net daily build best practices using Subversion

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, nightly-build

I am planning to have a daily build in CruiseControl.net using subversion. I would like to find out if it is better practice to pull down the code and get the revision number or tag the Subversion repository and pull it down from that tag? What are the pros and cons for the two different approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to pull the code down and use the revision number to version my assemblies.  This makes it easy to look at any assembly and know what revision of code I need to pull to recreate it.  It seems like tagging would be more useful for releases, as opposed to having one created every day.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a tag per day is overkill (in my opinion). A tag is better suited for abstract differences and modifications (new versions/features, hot fixes, etc).

Using the revision number allows you to achieve your goals without overcrowding your repository.